# Minecraft textures in 1.7.* turn black?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every single time I place a 2d item, all the textures go black, can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Saying "latest" isn't helpful: which actual version is it? (It will say beside the play button in the launcher.) Also, do you have any mods installed?

Comment: My best guess is that you actually have a texture pack installed that isn't compatible with the newer version. Make sure you are running the default texture pack or look for an update for the one you use.

Comment: @Morinar It is now not possible for texure packs to be incompatible, as each texture is applied independently, and the game falls back to default if no pack data is present. **Asteroid cat**, please clarify - which textures go black? Can you attach a screenshot? If you are talking about armor slots, it is a known bug.

Comment: I have seen this happen to a handful of people now but have no direct solutions as no one is really sure what the cause is as of yet. Its like the lighting just suddenly goes away and you are left with nothing but a black environment. People some times have to reinstall Minecraft (there are many ways to do that posted on line)

Comment: Yes, screenshot please!

Comment: I had this happen before, my 2d textures were corrupt. Have you tried redownloading the pack/reinstalling java?

Answer (score 0):

ah, sounds like a texture processing error (happened to me in multiple games!), its an OpenGL bug, try triggering the OpenGL option in the option menu of Minecraft, or try re-installing your graphic card drivers!